# Entity model can't find the connection string in app config.

Tags: c#, vb.net, entity-framework

i have an entity model contained in a dll and i am writing some unit tests for it. when i run it it says the connection string can't be found in the application config.

Data:
 model:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
      <!-- This section defines the logging configuration for My.Application.Log -->
      <source name="DefaultSource" switchName="DefaultSwitch">
        <listeners>
          <add name="FileLog" />
          <!-- Uncomment the below section to write to the Application Event Log -->
          <!--<add name="EventLog"/>-->
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
    <switches>
      <add name="DefaultSwitch" value="Information" />
    </switches>
    <sharedListeners>
      <add name="FileLog" type="Microsoft.VisualBasic.Logging.FileLogTraceListener, Microsoft.VisualBasic, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL" initializeData="FileLogWriter" />
      <!-- Uncomment the below section and replace APPLICATION_NAME with the name of your application to write to the Application Event Log -->
      <!--<add name="EventLog" type="System.Diagnostics.EventLogTraceListener" initializeData="APPLICATION_NAME"/> -->
    </sharedListeners>
  </system.diagnostics>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="efContext" 
         connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.efModel.csdl|res://*/Models.efModel.ssdl|res://*/Models.efModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=.;initial catalog=Production;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" 
         providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v12.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

the connection string is clearly in there. 
When my test calls a function within the dll  which is written like this

```
Public Function Find(ByVal SectionId As Integer) As Data.Section Implements ISection.Find

            Dim SectId As String = SectionId.ToString()

            Using dataContext As efContext = New efContext()

                dataContext.Database.Connection.ConnectionString = _efConnectionString

                Dim c As Data.Section = Nothing

                c = (From cs In dataContext.Sections
                            Where cs.SectionId = SectId).FirstOrDefault()

                Return c

            End Using

        End Function
```

it fails on dataContext.Database.Connection.ConnectionString = _efConnectionString

although when i debug it it already has the exception.

I tried duplicating the app config in the unit test project. I tried linking the app config as a shortcut. I have been stuck on this for about a full day now. I have tried just about every solution i have seen on stack overflow. it just doesn't seem to work.

I have even tried remaking the entity model and that didn't help either. 
Any ideas?

Comment: You didn't post the code that set's _efConnectionString, so it's hard to say.  From just this code, _efConnectionString is null, thus will throw an error.  Also, eww VB....

Comment: Also posting the exception may help

Comment: Hi, (personally) Firstly I would install entity framework on your test project and see if that works (bad practise). I would like to see if it's a code issue or just EF. (Please uninstall after). Difference between a unit test and an integration test.

Comment: @Ryios The DataBase.Connection *should* be set on the context= new Context()

Comment: _efConnectionString is not being set here, show the code. You create a new context and _efConnectionString is in the scope the context is being created in, leads me to belief you have a variable "_efConnectionString" and never set it to anything.

Comment: What does your context object look like?

Comment: Are you using a few project in your solution? if YES, you have to have connection string defined in starting project. If Entity Framework is used in other project than starting one, you have to move/copy connection string to starting project.

Comment: @P.K. yes i finially got it, this is the answer that helped me thanks